# Is there any computation or power used to keep npm running?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm new to node, and running my app on my own machine via the command `npm run start`.  When I'm done working on the project for the day, is there any reason to stop the process from continuing?  I currently have no other node.js project right now, but if I did, I imagine I would only be able to run one npm process at a time. Is this correct?

Without another node project to worry about, does the process run in a costly loop or do anything that might have unintended consequences for leaving it on 24/7?

Comment: "I imagine I would only be able to run one npm process at a time" why is that? Usually `npm run start` starts some node server. You could run it as many times assuming you have implemented some sort of port discovery.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I was making that assumption based on the app being accessed through localhost:9000.  If I start another app, they would compete for that spot.  Knowing the term now, I'll look up port discovery!

Answer (score -1):

check **forever** and **pm2** npm module. pm2 allows you to keep applications alive forever,These modules might help to reload them without downtime and to facilitate common system admin tasks and forever is being used for ensuring that a given script runs continuously.